cyclotomic extension and find an intermediate field


These graphs are from GTM 167. I am confused about that how we can generate the equation that ($x$-$\omega$)($x$-$\sigma_6$($\omega$))  =($x$-$\omega$)($x$-$\omega^6$)(in the middle of the graph). In other word, what is our motivation to construct this to support us finding $L$ as an intermediate field. It says there is a quadratic but why must be this one?

Why this one?   Note that $\omega$ and $\omega^6$ are complex conjugates, so their sum and product are real

$\omega$ has a quadratic minimal polynomial over $L$ because $[K:L]=2$ and $K=L(\omega)$. Moreover, $L$ is the fixed field under $\langle \sigma_6\rangle$, so if $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $L$, then $\sigma_6(\omega)=\omega^6$ is also a root of $p$.

@schiepy, I think this interpretation is good. $\sigma_6$ plays a role in permuting the roots of this quadratic minimal polynomial.
